# Отправка token в header angular

Tags: angularjs

Пытаюсь изучать angular. Для написания отзыва о продукте на сервисе, нужно передать `token` в заголовке http-запроса. Как это можно сделать? 
Вот код:

```
$scope.savingcomment = function (answer, answerForm){
      console.log($scope.answer.comment);
             $http.post("http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/reviews/2",{"rate":5,"text":"fffddf"}).success(function (answ) {
              console.log($scope.answer.comment);
            })
              .error(function (err) {
    console.log('Что-то пошло не так');
}) 
};
```

Comment: что за токен? что за заголовок?

Answer (score 1):

Например можно сделать так. Взято с оф. документации же. Соответственно в *headers* можно передать любой хедер, в т.ч. и токен ваш, как вам нужно.

```
 var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://example.com',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': undefined
     },
     data: { test: 'test' }
    }

    $http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```